# Multiple wildcard types keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this data:

```
{

    name1: 'name',
    name2: [{},{},{}],
    name3: true,
}
```

And I want to type it. Name1, name2, and name3 are created automatically, and may have other names, but the structure is like this.

How do I type this?

I tried doing smth like this:

```
export type data = {
  [key: string]: boolean;
  [key: string]: number;
  [key: string]: Array<MachineMapping>;
};
```

But now I'm getting:

```
Duplicate index signature for type 'string'.
```

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union.

```
export type data = {
  [key: string]: boolean | number | Array<MachineMapping>;
};
```

Comment: God damn it that's simple. I was having a smooth-brain moment there. Thanks!